# Best way to send registration email (DEVISE)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

Devise allows you to customize mailers here. 
https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Use-custom-mailer.

However, I can also make a my own actionmailer like here. 
http://railscasts.com/episodes/206-action-mailer-in-rails-3

When a user registers on my site, I would like to send two different emails, one to myself with the registration information and one to the user to thank them for registering.

What is the best way to do this? or is there a method that devise has that would allow me to do this?  I was thinking of creating a hook(call back) in the model after a user is created. However, that would mean if I manually create a record, the registration emails would also be sent out.  I don't want an email to be sent out if I manually create a user.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1):

You could have a callback such as `after_create :send_email_to_admin`

```
def send_email_to_admin
  # your implementation
end
```

You would also put a conditional so it doesn't send an email when it's yourself creating the record manually. I do not think Devise offers such an option.

Answer (score 1):

3 workarounds if you don't want to send email to your manually created users.

1. Create users at first, then add the hook.
2. Add a special pattern on the email of your manually created users. Say `(.*)-very-weird-suffix@weired-email.com`. You judge this pattern in the hook.
3. Add a field in users table to check if the account is created by you. I really don't recommend this unless creating accounts is part of your daily job.

Comment: @billy_chan 1) would mean I can never in the future manually add more users, not the best solution for me.--- Unless I misunderstand what you mean.  2) interesting idea, but it requires the user to be aware of it, I don't trust the admin users  3) Is what I originally thought of, but was not sure. Why don't you recommend 3?

Comment: @user2012677, actually you can still do it in the future with #1, just with a little bit hassle of receiving emails. I guess that would not be too much. Anyway you can still consider #2 and #3, depending on your own workflow.

Comment: @user2012677, I don't prefer #3 because it adds extra field in users table. I prefer to keep clean if possible. But, if you want to do it without communication with admin, I'm afraid that's the only way to go.